# Error in Chapter $8$ of Stein's Complex Analysis?

Tags: complex-analysis

The "positive square root" mentioned here is log$|z|$+$i$arg$(z)$ and the "negative square root" is log$|z|$+$i[$arg$(z)+2\pi]$.  In the middle of the page I penciled in a minus sign in front of the $i$ because that is what you get if you use the positive square root for the case $\zeta>1$.  But then the segments $A$ and $C$ would be mapped onto the lower half plane, and now I don't know what to make of their claim that this function is the inverse of $\sin(z)$.  Do they want to use the negative square root instead which does give $i$?  But then $B'$ is reversed which messes with the continuity.

In conclusion: I see now now how to explain this.  The answer below is right (or at least has the right idea; I think it needs a little more explanation).  I have deleted all the previous edits and comments for clarity because there was a lot written that was confusing and wrong.  The idea is simply that the branch is chosen so that arg$(1-\zeta^{2})$ is $0$ when $|\zeta|<1$ (or any multiple of $4\pi$ because this corresponds to positive square root.)  The question now reduces to figuring out what arg$(1-\zeta^{2})$ is for $\zeta>1$, which is not that hard.  If $|z_{0}|<1$ and $z>1$, then as $\zeta$ travels from $z_{0}$ to $z$ in the upper half plane (recall $\zeta$ cannot belong to the two forbidden half lines in the lower half plane), $1-\zeta^{2}$ approaches $1-z^{2}$ from below.  Hence arg$(-1)=-\pi$ and this explains why the text gets $i$ and not $-i$.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The point is that we want the integrand to be continuous from above on $\mathbb R \setminus \{-1, 1\}$ to be able to deform the integration contour to $[0, z]$ if $z$ is real. Verify that if you choose a branch which is analytic in the upper half-plane and positive on $(-1, 1)$, the limit from above at $\zeta > 1$ is $+i (\zeta^2 - 1)^{-1/2}$, where $(\zeta^2 - 1)^{-1/2}$ is positive.

Comment: The requirements that I listed already uniquely determine the function in the closed upper half-plane. If you want an analytic expression, you can take $g(\zeta) = (1 - \zeta^2)^{-1/2}$ for $\operatorname{Im} \zeta > 0 \lor \zeta < 1$ and $g(\zeta) = -(1 - \zeta^2)^{-1/2}$ for $\zeta > 1$, where $z^{-1/2}$ means the principal branch.

Comment: The principal branch means that $z^{-1/2} = |z|^{-1/2} e^{-i \arg(z)/2}, \, -\pi < \arg z \leq \pi$. Give me a point $\zeta$ where $g(\zeta)$ from my previous comment (or the associated $f(\zeta)$) does not match any of the requirements.

Comment: Like I said, give me a point $\zeta$ in the upper half-plane where $g$ isn't holomorphic or a point on $\mathbb R \setminus \{-1, 1\}$ where $g$ is not continuous. Feel free to rewrite $z^{-1/2} = e^{-\ln(z)/2}$, $\ln z = \ln |z| + i \arg z, \, -\pi < \arg z \leq \pi$.

Comment: But I said $g$ from *my* previous comment:
$$g(\zeta) = (1 - \zeta^2)^{-1/2} \cases {
1 & $\operatorname{Im} \zeta > 0 \lor \zeta < 1$ \\
-1 & $\zeta > 1$}, \\
f(z) = \int_0^z g(\zeta) \, d\zeta.$$
Then $g(2) = -(-3)^{-1/2} = i/\sqrt 3$ (using any of the two identical definitions of $z^{-1/2}$ from *my* comments above. There is nothing special about the points $1 - (1 \pm i)^2 = 1 \mp 2 i$, they're not on the branch cut of $z^{-1/2}$.

Comment: $(|z| e^{i \arg z})^{-1/2} = |z|^{-1/2} e^{-i \arg(z)/2}, \, -\pi < \arg z \leq \pi$ is exactly what I wrote above (twice, in two different forms). You have failed to give a specific example of where this doesn't work (and deleted your comments).

Comment: $(-3)^{-1/2} = -i/\sqrt 3$ (since, once again, I take $-\pi < \arg z \leq \pi$), $g(2) = -(-3)^{-1/2} = i/\sqrt 3$, which is exactly what I wrote above. Where is the problem?

Comment: Since you're not claiming that this is wrong and doesn't work, we're making progress. The book says "choose the branch". It appeared to me that you wanted to construct an analytic expression for this branch. $g$ gives such an expression in a fairly simple form. If you do not want to understand why this $g$ works (and, in fact, what "works" means -- why we're requiring analyticity in the upper half-plane and continuity on $\mathbb R \setminus \{-1, 1\}$), that, of course, is entirely up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that it says "when $\zeta > 1$".

Consider the complex number $\zeta = x+i\epsilon$, where $x>1\gg\epsilon>0$. Then $1-\zeta^2 = -(x^2-1-\epsilon^2)- 2ix\epsilon$ has a negative real and imaginary part, and so will be mapped to the fourth quadrant near the imaginary axis. In particular, in the limit that $\epsilon\rightarrow 0^+$, $(1-\zeta^2)^{1/2} \rightarrow - i(x^2-1)^{1/2}$, and accordingly $(1-\zeta^2)^{-1/2} \rightarrow  i(x^2-1)^{-1/2}$.

For $\zeta < 1$, the opposite is true. Then $(1-\zeta^2)^{-1/2}\rightarrow -i(x^2-1)^{-1/2}$, by a similar argument to the above.

Comment: $\log(z)$ is discontinuous for negative real values of $z$, approaching $\log|z| + i\pi$ from the upper half-plane and $\log|z| - i\pi$ from the lower half-plane. The purpose of the limiting argument is to determine which direction it is being approached from, which then tells us which value to use.

Comment: @SihOASHoihd [This](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot3D%5BIm%5BSqrt%5B1+-+(x+%2B+I*y)%5E2%5D%5D,+%7Bx,+-3,+3%7D,+%7By,+0,+3%7D%5D) is a plot of $\mathrm{Im}[\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}]$ for the upper half-plane. Notice how the imaginary part is negative for $\zeta > 1$ and positive for $\zeta < -1$.